# How would you find the probability of selecting 3 red marble and 2 green marble or 1 yellow marble and 2 orange marble out of a bag of 12 marbles

Tags: probability

How would you find the probability of selecting 1 red marble and 1 green marble or 1 yellow marble and 1 orange marble out of a bag of 12 marbles

There are four red marbles,one green marble, one yellow marble, six orange marbles

Comment: how many of each type are in the bag??

Comment: @SakethMalyala I added amount of each type in edit

Comment: Have you tried to solve this on your own?

Comment: Yep I have tried

Comment: Are you finding the probability for each case or the cases combined?

Comment: And are the marbles replaced?

Comment: Are we to assume that two marbles are selected without replacement?

Comment: No the marbles are not replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer I'm assuming that the asker means to find the probability of the cases combined, and that the order in which he listed the marbles is the order that they are picked:
The probability of picking a red marble is $4/12$. The probability of picking a green marble is $1/11$, since I'm assuming that the marbles are not replaced. You multiply since you want both of these occuring. $1/3$ times $1/11$ equals $1/33$.
Try to apply this logic to the orange and yellow marbles, then multiply the results.

Comment: Thanks for answering!!!!!